# Error Stopped listening on port 62157 - Selenium geckodriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Driver set up:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", getConfigProp.getFirefoxDriverPath());
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.setCapability("marionette", true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

@AfterMethod
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Firefox version: 90.0.2(32-bit), Geckodriver Version - 0.29.1 Win32

It runs first method in test file and then gives below error.
628139819769    Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 62157
[Parent 12464, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_win.cc:167
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."